# Apache Camel - Delay when exception occurs

Tags: apache-camel

I have written a camel route that polls a file folder, picks up request, checks for memory consumption on server (in a java file). If its below threshold it drops the request on a JMS queue otherwise it throws an exception and picks it again for processing.

What i need to do is that when exception is thrown i need to delay processing for a configurable amount of time say 15 mins. This will give some time for server to stabilize instead of keeping it polling unnecessarily.
I am using errorHandler mechanism of camel however it doesnt seem to work. Camle keeps on picking up the request without any delay. Please help with this issue.
Below is the bundle context snapshot:

```
<camel:onException>
        <camel:exception>java.lang.Exception</camel:exception>
        <camel:redeliveryPolicy backOffMultiplier="500" />
        <camel:log message="Default error handler was called"></camel:log>
    </camel:onException>
            <camel:route>
                <!--  Reading from REST url -->
                <camel:from uri="<my url>" />
                <!--  If else loop -->
                <camel:choice>
                    <camel:when>
                        <camel:xpath>Some path</camel:xpath>
                        <!--  Parsing OrderNumber and OrderVersion-->
                        <camel:log message="Recieved request ${headers.OrderNumber}-${headers.OrderVersion}.xml"/>
                        <camel:setHeader headerName="OrderNumber">
                            <xpath>Some path</xpath>
                        </camel:setHeader>
                        <camel:setHeader headerName="OrderVersion">
                            <camel:xpath>Some path</camel:xpath>
                        </camel:setHeader>
                        <!-- Request being put in file folder -->
                        <to
                            uri="file:data/inbox?fileName=${header.OrderNumber}-${header.OrderVersion}.xml"
                            pattern="InOut" />
                    </camel:when>
                    <!--  For all other requests put on  queue -->
                    <camel:otherwise>
                        <camel:log message="Request ${headers.OrderNumber}-${headers.OrderVersion}.xml directly sent to  queue"/>
                            <to uri="my queue"
                                pattern="InOut" />
                    </camel:otherwise>
                </camel:choice>
            </camel:route>
            <camel:route errorHandlerRef="errorHandler">
            <!-- Route to put message from folder to JMS queue if memory consumption is below limit-->
                <camel:from uri="file:data/inbox"/>
                    <camel:process ref="checkMemoryConsumption"/>
                    <camel:convertBodyTo type="String" />
                    <camel:log message="Sucessfully processing service order ${headers.OrderNumber}-${headers.OrderVersion}.xml"/>
                    <to uri="my queue"
                            pattern="InOut" />
            </camel:route>
```

Comment: You can use the backoffMultiplier in case of error to poll much later - http://camel.apache.org/file2

Comment: As Claus has indicated use the backoffMultiplier.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I added onException handling and tried to configure backoffMultiplier in there but still running into same issue. Polling goes on endlessly without any delay.                                                                                    <camel:onException>
  <camel:exception>java.lang.Exception</camel:exception>
  <camel:redeliveryPolicy backOffMultiplier="500" />
  <camel:log message="Default error handler was called"></camel:log></camel:onException>. I have posted updated bundle context as well. Please let me know what am I missing here.

Comment: No on the consumer, see http://camel.apache.org/file2

Comment: @Claus Ibsen - Is it that maximumRedeliveries and redeliveryDelay go hand in hand? As you can see in my case I wanted the request to be polled until its successfully processed and didnt specific maximumRedeliveries in my route and only delay. However because of this delay mechanism was also not working. Only when i defined maximumRedeliveries and redeliveryDelay, did the delay took effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `redeliveryDelay` of `redeliveryPolicyProfile`?

Below policy profile will retry 3 times with the delay of 1000mS between each try.

```
<redeliveryPolicyProfile id="myRedeliveryProfile"
        maximumRedeliveries="3"
        redeliveryDelay="1000" allowRedeliveryWhileStopping="false"
        retryAttemptedLogLevel="INFO" />
```

Read more on [here](http://camel.apache.org/redeliverypolicy.html)

Comment: I tried redeliveryPolicy "camel:redeliveryPolicy". The mistake i was making was that i didnt include 'maximumRedeliveries' as in my case i wanted retry to happen as long as request doesnt get processed and not a specific no of times. For now I have added this tag and it seems to work. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

By making below modification in my bundle context (bundle context displayed above), re-delivery policy kicked in and seems to do the trick.