# Delay an Apache Camel route trigger if exception happened during last time processing

Tags: java, apache-camel

Is there any built-in mechanism in **Apache Camel** to delay next triggering time of a route when exception occurred during last route processing?

For example, if I have a route:

- trigger every 5 seconds
- fetch data from database
- process data and build a message
- send message to remote ActiveMQ instance

I want to be able to handle this scenario:

If database or ActiveMQ will go down (maintenance or some network issues), causing exceptions to be thrown during route processing, I want to temporary delay next time route will be triggered (like wait 5 mins before triggering again, giving some time to restart database\activemq) and switch back to 5 seconds trigger when route processed with no exceptions again. Or even gradually increase wait time for next trigger on every failed attempt to process with no fails (1min/5min/10 min) and switch back to default of 5 seconds when everything is fine.

I can build my own workaround using processors, `onException` handlers, some array to remember current delay status per routeId and `choice()` predicates that skips whole route from running if it is delayed, but maybe there is some built in mechanism in **Apache Camel**, as it sounds like a usual use-case scenario?

Comment: `redeliveryDelay` might suit your need, see [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30213291/3759505)

Comment: The circuit breaker EIP is supported.

Comment: Based on the solution you expect, this what you need I believe
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309081/camel-runtime-timer-change

Answer (score 0):

You can use Throtling route policy when consuming from MQ, Kafka. With Throtling Route Policy, you can control the data fetech from source if there are any issues with sink systems